# How do you create an retargetable action for a specific object type in Eclipse using the commands framework?

Tags: eclipse, command, selection

The Eclipse command framework allows you to create a generic command and handler. However, when you create an extension point that targets 'copy' the runtime complains:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
 <handler class="example.Handler" commandId="org.eclipse.ui.edit.copy"/>
</extension>

!MESSAGE Conflicting handlers for org.eclipse.ui.edit.copy: {org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WidgetMethodHandler:copy} vs {example.Handler}
```

If you add an `activeWhen` clause, so that the special handler is only invoked when an object of a particular type is selected in a viewer, then you get an exception when you try and copy:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
 <handler class="example.Handler" commandId="org.eclipse.ui.edit.copy">
     <activeWhen>
        <with
              variable="selection">
           <iterate
                 ifEmpty="false"
                 operator="or">
              <instanceof
                    value="sample.Class">
              </instanceof>
           </iterate>
        </with>
     </activeWhen>
   </handler>
</extension>

Caused by: org.eclipse.core.commands.NotHandledException: There is no handler to execute for command org.eclipse.ui.edit.copy
```

What's the right way of using the commands framework to provide a specific copy operation for objects of a particular type?

Comment: Paul Webster is likely your best bet for cmd handler questions. I'm not sure if he monitors SOF.

Comment: Yeah, he's on here (http://stackoverflow.com/users/713646/paul-webster) but I don't know if he monitors it regularly. I figured it would be a good place to host an answer if he did, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `activeWhen` clause looks acceptable.  What will matter is what selection you are going for.  ex:

```
  <handler class="z.ex.cmd.handlers.LongCopyHandler"
        commandId="org.eclipse.ui.edit.copy">
     <activeWhen>
        <with variable="selection">
           <iterate ifEmpty="false"
                 operator="and">
              <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IMarker"/>
           </iterate>
        </with>
     </activeWhen>
  </handler>
```

I originally tried `instanceof` in my activeWhen expression to get access to the IMarkers in the markers view, but that didn't work (the objects don't implement IMarker).  I had to `adapt` them to get my handler to work correctly. This would apply to .java files in the Package Explorer as well, they adapt to an `IResource` but they're actually IJavaElements or something.

Comment: This was in a viewer with my own custom data type, so it was definitely the right class (as opposed to something that needed adapting).

Is the warning (conflicting handlers) something to be expected?